# Fujitsu Siemens Laptop Problems

Tags: windows-xp, boot, hardware-failure, hard-drive-recovery

I've got a Fujitsu Siemens Laptop running XP and have had problems booting.

At first the message was to do with corrupt registry files, System, Security etc. I replaced all of the files with ones from the recovery folder and I got passed that screen and onto the boot options, safe mode, start normally etc.

When I select start normally or last best configuration all I get is a flashing cursor and it just stops there. If I select safe mode it starts loading files until It gets to mup.sys and hangs. If I try and use the XP disc to do a repair or new install of XP it loads all of the drivers then hangs on setup is starting windows. I have disabled everything I can in BIOS and removed all devices and the problem still persists.

I have also attempted booting Linux from a live disc which have also failed to work.

I have removed the HDD and backed up all the content by plugging it into a external USB HDD adapter so losing files is not an issue.

I suspect that it must be some kind of hardware failure, the RAM maybe, but would like to see what others thought and if there was anything else that I could try. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with an inspection of the hard drive and it's health. If you can load up to a certain point and then things start to hang, it would be a good logical first step.

Although you are running win xp there is a question in super user [How can I read my hard drives SMART status in windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7) that has several suggestions for third party software to check the health of your hard drive and they will work with XP. And good job on salvaging your data to other storage, if it is your drive and it is failing, you took the best precaution.