# Vista 64-bit, DISK BOOT FAILURE

Tags: windows, windows-vista

So I have this [Acer Aspire AX3200-U3600A](http://reviews.cnet.com/desktops/acer-aspire-ax3200-u3600a/4505-3118_7-33345347.html) with Windows Vista (64-bit). Every night I turn it off and turn it back on in the morning.

Around three weeks ago, I did a fresh factory reimage. Good as new.

Then around two days ago, when I turned it on, I noticed it was running extremly slow. As in, it would often freeze up while I had multiple applications open when it usually never froze up. So I decided to restart my computer. Big mistake.

My computer froze right after I clicked shut-down. I waited a while. Nothing. Waited some minutes. Nope. I decided to shut it down by pressing the power button. Here is where the problems begin.

When I turned it back on, I saw the Windows logo and loading bar and then it loaded to black. I turned it off again forcefully by power button and then once more... then I got:

```
AMD Data Change... Update New Data to DMI!
```

then later the screen clears and I get:

```
AHCI Option ROM BIOS Revision: 01.05.92 Date: 02-19-2008
Copyright (c) 2006-2008 Phoenix Technologies, LTD

Port 01: Reset Port Error!!
Port 02:
```

then the screen clears again but this time, this loads from the bottom:

```
Nvidia Boot Agent 249.0542
(copyright stuff... blah blah)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable.
PXE-M0F: Exiting Nvidia Boot Agent

DISK BOOT FAILURE, INSERT SYSTEM DISK AND PRESS ENTER.
```

So I try to go into Safe Mode. Well, first of all it doesn't load as fast. After it loads `disk.sys` from `windows/drivers`, it will wait a while (2-3 mins) THEN load. However it loads the `Acer eRecovery Management Tool`. I have three options: `Reset computer to factory default`, `Restore computer from user's backup`, or `Exit`. **However**, the top two options are gray and disabled where as the `Exit` is in blue and definitely clickable. So obviously safe mode is not there...

**A strong thing to note:** In the beginning when all of this started, I did a `Boot Windows Normal` from pressing `f8` and I got to my desktop! It logged me in. I could see the icons on my files. However my desktop was extremely slow as in when I clicked on the Start menu, it would wait a while, then load up the menu with JUST the gradient, no text or icons... so as you can see... it saw my HDD?

Also, before anyone says, I have NO USB plugged in. My mouse and keyboard are not USB inputs, I assure you. And this came without a recovery CD AND when I went in `BIOS`, to change the BOOT ORDER, I did NOT see a `CD-ROM` option. And when I tried pressing `ALT+F10` to get into Acer eRecovery Management, the top two options were disabled as well.

But sometimes on start-up, I get:

> Windows has encountered a problem communicating with a device
>   connected to your computer.
>
> This error can be caused by unplugging a removable storage device such
>   as an external USB drive while the device is in use, or by faulty
>   hardware such as a hard drive or CD-ROM drive that is failing. Make
>   sure any removeable storage is properly connected and then restart
>   your computer.
>
> If you continue to receive this error message, contact the hardware
>   manufacturer.
>
> Status: 0xc00000e9
>
> Info: An unexpected I/O error has occured.

Then I tried `Last Known Good Configuration Settings`, that gives me a BSOD.

What should I do/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The symptoms you are describing are pretty close to a drive failure.  Check the drive health (called SMART status) when you can.  It's not conclusive, but if it tells you there are issues, there are definitely issues.

Comment: How do I get to this `SMART status`?

Comment: Read this:  http://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

Replace the cmos battery with a new one, then immediately enter the bios and load defaults and set Date and Time.

It does sound like a more serious motherboard, hard drive, or cable problem, but I would start with the battery.