# Find and delete uncopyable files

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, file-recovery

I have a PC with a hdd in it. All it has is mkv I have ripped from my own DVD and bluray. I have been suspecting that this drive is on its way out as it is becoming noisy and the sound pulsates. So I bought myself a NAS drive and attempted to copy off the files before it failed irrevocably.

It appears that some files are broken in some way and I don't know how many. The copy would be going fine and then it would hit a file and copying would cease (the network performance tab in task manager would show 0%) for about 5 minutes upon which time it would ask if I would like to retry or skip. Retry causes it to pause for another 5 minutes while skipping causes it to wait 5 minutes before going to the next file.

I would like to be able to automatically scan the the files looking for these errors and mark the files that are broken so I can rerip and then delete them.

I have tried windows chkdsk and scan disk but the former found zero errors and the latter only does system files?

I have tried playing these files and they are unplayable. I would rather not spend several hours possibly watching Windows decide that the file is broken and uncopyable and manually telling it to skip.

A Google search reveals a lot of Microsoft pages on system file repair and a lot of questions with little in the way of answers beyond tools that would try to open them.

Does anyone know of any tools to do this? A Linux live disk would also suffice if it does what I need it to and comes with detailed instructions.

**UPDATE:** I started looking for raw copiers but I am suspecting that they will copy everything including errors. Also they overwrite everything on the disk so I will be swapping out a drive for a spare 2gb I had left over from my NAS.

No tools anyone can recommend?

Comment: Have you done a SMART scan? [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240)

Comment: No, I haven't but the fact that a) it sounds sick and b) trying to copy files off is revealing damaged files means it needs to be replaced and the good files copied off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could copy your HDD to your NAS with something like [Robocopy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc733145%28v=WS.10%29.aspx).
It is capable to mirror an entire directory structure and is also robust when it comes to unreadable files.
Something like `robocopy /old/hdd /new/NAS /mir /r:1 /w:3 /log:/path/to/logfile /tee` should do it.

- robocopy source destination
- /mir - Mirrors a directory structure
- /r:1 - If file is unreadable retry to copy it 1 more time
- /w:3 - Wait 3 seconds before retrying to copy an unreadable file again
- /log:/path/ - Write logfile to /path/
- /tee - Write to log and also output to console window

So your HDD would be synced to your NAS and you get a log where you can see which files were skipped.

Comment: Hits the same issue as doing it through explorer but at least I can see which files are failing and have a log of it. The error given for the first failing file it has spent in excess of 20 minutes on apparently is CRC.

Comment: For ignoring errors you could try to set `/r:0 /w:0` but I don't know if the files get logged as not readable.

Comment: Just got back in. In 7 1/2 hours it has processed 21 files and 50% of them are bad.

Comment: It finally completed the entirety of the drive last night between 8pm and 1030pm, so it took 36 hours.  No directories escaped unscathed but I managed to get 270gb off it, which is less than 1gb per hour.