# Windows 8.1 completely hangs whenever connecting to wireless networks

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade, lenovo-laptop

Whenever the laptop connects (or automatically connects on start-up) to a wireless network, Windows completely hangs (screen freezes; mouse and keyboard has no effect; <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Del</kbd> has no effect), and it is necessary to force a shutdown by pressing the power button for 5 seconds.

It also has a few other issues, including taking a long time to start up, despite having only the usual programmes installed when buying from a computer shop.

I was going to attempt to install Windows 10, but I then realised that you need to install updates to upgrade for free, which obviously cannot happen while Windows refuses to connect to any wireless network.

I would tell my friend (an elderly lady) to take it back to the shop, but it is no longer covered by the original guarantee (she bought it over 1 year ago). She bought it from PC World (in the UK), if that's any help.

The laptop is a *[Lenovo G500](http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/lenovo/g-series/g500/)* (**Windows 8.1 Home N**) with a 2.4 GHz Intel Pentium Inside processor, 4 GiB installed RAM, and only the default drivers installed. No extra applications, other than the ones it came installed with, and has not been used much.

Any ideas on what the problem could be, or how to get a free update to Windows 10?

Comment: Failing hard disk? Try running some SMART tests [How can I read my hard drive's SMART status in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/q/29240). You will need to run the test software from a USB thumb drive as the laptop doesn't have an ethernet port or CD drive.

Comment: Have you scanned for malware? You'd need to to make a rescue disk or USB drive, such as ESET, Kaspersky or MalwareByte. You might also try to boot from a Linux disk, such as Ubuntu, from which would determine if the HDD is failing. One more thought -- it might be connecting, and trying to do a year's worth of updates at once!

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually, the laptop has both an Ethernet port and a CD/DVD ROM drive.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Yes, I was going to try using a Kapersky Rescue Live CD (I've got a couple, a newer and an older one). Also, Windows crashes the moment it connects – **all** of Windows, not just DWM or the GUI.

Comment: @toothbrush Yes, I missed the "Integrated Comms" in the spec, but there is no mention of a DVD. http://shop.lenovo.com/gb/en/laptops/lenovo/g-series/g500/#tab-tech_specs

Comment: @toothbrush As we now know it has ethernet does it also crash when using a wired connection?

Comment: @DavidPostill I am going to check that tomorrow – I'll get back to you then. Also, it definitely has a CD/DVD R/W drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Windows 8 by switching the laptop off with the power button each time Windows started to load (3 times). That started Recovery Mode, and I reinstalled Windows, wiping the hard drive (there wasn't anything important on it) – and forced an update to Windows 10.

Since it worked after reinstalling, I assume that the configuration/driver was corrupted.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Installing Windows 10 solved my issue.

Comment: @Lucky I'm glad to hear it solved the problem. Reinstalling Windows solves a lot of problems... **:)**

Comment: Here in India it came with a DOS OS. I reinstalled different Windows 7 and Windows 8 many times in my G500 laptop. But I was having the same problem again and again. But the funny thing is the laptop is designed to support for 7 & 8. I installed Windows 10 OS with Windows 8.1 drivers which is actually unsupported by Lenovo and luckily it got solved. ;)

Comment: @Lucky I have a problem with my laptop where the touchpad only allows you to move the mouse and right-click. Pretty weird, but it works for roughly 1 month after I reinstall Windows 7 – although the version is Ultimate, so I can't upgrade for free. It is probably something to do with the drivers, but I've reinstalled Windows 7 6–7 times over the last 3 years, and don't want to do it anymore. I use a wireless mouse all the time, so I can't be bothered to find the problem, but it **is** annoying that I have to take a mouse with me whenever I take it out.

Comment: I have installed the [Synaptics touchpad driver](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds035159) without any touchpad issues. Try installing the driver if you haven't. Thanks.

Comment: @Lucky BTW, you write very good English! A large proportion of "English speakers" in India do _not_ know the proper context for lots of words, and their grammar is horrible... it can be so hard to understand them on some forums.

Comment: @Lucky Thank you. I may have installed it in the past, but I'll try it again.