# Asus laptop - Works but is VERY SLOW

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance, asus-laptop

I have a fairly new ASUS laptop computer.  It's a cheap Walmart model, but it worked fine for a while.  One day, for no apparent reason, it began working very slow.  It does work but it takes about half an hour just to boot up.  I re-installed Windows 7 (a very long process) but it didn't help.  Applications seem to work, if you let it sit all day to do something.  Any ideas on what might be causing this?   Thanks.

Comment: Is it any different in safe mode? If so, you may have a rogue program which is hogging the CPU, disc or both: TaskManager should help you to identify it. If not, you may have a failing disc, so look at the disc's SMART data with one of the programs recommended in the answers [here](http://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7).

Comment: "I re-installed Windows 7 (a very long process) ' - This tells me the HDD is bad.

Comment: Thanks to all who gave some input.  I wasn't able to log in to safe mode- not sure why.  In the meantime, I managed to get another laptop running, so I'm going to stop messing with the Asus  Again, I appreciate all of the input.

Answer (score -1):

Try booting to **safe mode**. If it is quick, you know the problem has to be with your startup applications on your normal boot.

Click `start` > `Run`. Type `msconfig` and hit Enter. In `System Configuration`, click on `Boot tab`. On the low half, under 'Boot options', check `Safe boot`. Click OK. Click Restart now on any dialog prompting you to restart your computer. 
If booting to safe mode is quick, you can be certain Normal Boot startup apps/services must be the problem.

Now you'll have to do the same as the previous paragraph but **this time in the last step, uncheck** `Safe boot`, and click OK and click "Restart now" on any dialog box prompting for a restart. You have no choice but to wait an hour if that's how long it takes. When it has booted up, you can try a minimal boot by disabling all Startup items and Non-Microsoft services, by:
`Start` > `Run`> type `msconfig`and hit Enter. Click on `Startup tab` click on Open Task Manager > Right click on each of the listed apps and click Disable so that their Status is disabled. Now close Task Manager, go back to msconfig, this time click on the `Services tab`**Check the box 'Hide all Microsoft services'(important!)**. Then uncheck every one of the services listed in the box by clicking 'Disable all'. Click Apply, and restart your PC.

If all goes well you'll have to do the same by enabling the Services / Programs one by one, starting from the ones that are less likely to impact Startup times, to the more suspicious bloated programs.

**If nothing changed even with Safe Mode, I suspect your harddrive might be dying**. It usually starts off with slow read speeds, then later you hear click noises or scratching noises, at this point your harddrive is close to death. Important step now is to back up your data immediately. To check whether your hard drive is dying I recommend `CrystalDiskInfo`(http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/index-e.html). Upon launching the program, you see your hard drive (C: usually). Things to check here are the overall 'Health status', and under the attributes below, are to check the attributes' 'Worst' column against the 'Threshold' column  to see if **any of 'Worst' values are lower than the 'Threshold' values**. If so, your harddisk is on the verge of dying and remember to back up your data immediately! And of course you'll have to get a replacement hard drive for your laptop.

Comment: Good answer, but the program you suggested feels very sketchy. I don't know why a simple and industry-standard SMART scan was not suggested.

Comment: 'It looks sketchy. That's what I thought the first time I was recommended it. The website is ad-filled and the author seems to have a comical design sense, but not in a bad way once you know that he's into Manga and likes that kind of design and feel in his stuff. Now I think it's actually one of the best SMART portable apps out there. The same author created the very well know CrystalDiskMark which many use to benchmark their ssds especially, that is a portable app too. Nowadays lots of open source software are better than the industry-enterprise standard software and this is one of such.