# Asus Windows 10 performance very slow and unresponsive (stuck in a flickering glitchy loop)

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, pdf

I'm dealing with an Asus Windows 10 laptop here.

The trouble started when my dad downloaded a PDF reader (All PDF Reader) on it to read some files. He tried to install it, but it didn't seem like it so he tried again until he did so three times, which is when it got slow and unresponsive and glitchy (almost like it's constantly refreshing). He gave the PC a hard shutdown. After restarting it, nothing changed.

After waiting some time after start-up, an error dialogue eventually pops up displaying the following info:

Title:

```
explorer.exe - Application Error
```

Message:

```
The exception unknown software exception (0xc06d007e) occurred in the application at location 0x00007FF86D31CB69.
```

I looked up various different solutions on YouTube and here, most of them involving things like *Start --> Run* or safe mode (see [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/996146/asus-laptop-works-but-is-very-slow) for example), unable to interact with the computer however, this was no viable option. In order to give my dad access to his files, I rebooted from a live Linux mint USB device, though I still couldn't give him access to move any files to another device (another story), everything else worked fine. After rebooting to Windows, the computer was glitchy again and the error was back.

I also tried fixing the problem from the BIOS but there weren't any relevant options there.

In Linux, I would normally switch to console mode in order to deal with a situation like this (ctrl+alt+F3), can something similar be done in Windows? Can anyone give me a solution involving remote access? Or perhaps a better idea if you know of something? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like your Dad got the computer infected, in spite of the antivirus fighting valiantly against the installation. Best advice is to reformat the disk and reinstall everything. If there is data to save, use a Linux Live USB.

Comment: @harrymc I tried using a live linux USB to retrieve and save his data, but I encountered another problem there (the system is in read-only mode), once I get around that, I definitely will try that though, I might consider posting another question on that.