# I am trying to recover this hard drive. Attached are my diskpart results for list volume. Has it failed?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop

diskpart results:

[image]

more diskpart results:

[image]

For background:

1. Putting it in an enclosure and plugging it into my machine got nothing and made weird noises. And my enclosure works because I just got it and used it to back up someone elses drive the day before.
2. On startup, i get the PXE-E61 error "Media test failure, check cable"
3. Diskpart results are linked
4. Both bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot say "The device is not ready". Bootrec /scanos found 0 windows installations, Bootrec /rebuildbcd did not find any either.

I have gone through many of the hard drive failure questions on this site but they all seemed to take some different approaches to mine and had different circumstances. I want to make absolutely sure this drive is gone before I tell my client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This hard drive seems like it was somewhat corrupted, but you might want to gather more evidence that it is "dead."

You are getting a PXE-E61 error because your computer is booting to PXE/network boot. Make sure that network boot is disabled. If it is already at the bottom of the boot order, this shows that the hard drive is not bootable.

The Diskpart results show that there is some trouble reading the disk, but in order to definitively determine whether or not your disk is on the verge of failure, you need to [check the drive's SMART data](https://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drives-smart-status-in-windows-7) for signs of wear and bad sectors.

If all SMART data turns out well, you will want to use TestDisk to try to regenerate the partition table so that the disk's partitions can be recognized again. If TestDisk fails to recover anything, then the disk is indeed dead.

Comment: Not sure why, but I was only able to access the BIOS once, when I changed the boot order to my install disc. Ever since every attempt to access the BIOS has left the screen hanging. I wasn't looking for it in particular, but I changed priority to the disc with the HDD second, so im pretty sure the network boot couldnt have been mixed in that. I just booted into PartedMagic and I can't even get the drive to appear to check SMART data.The wmic diskdrive get status command returns Status Ok.