# Windows 10 Cyclic Disk Errors, Applications Randomly Stop Responding, DiskPart Stuck on Blinking cursor. Source of the problems?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, freeze, diskpart

I have a windows 10 PC with 3 drives, a 100 GB SD from which the system boots, along with a 1 and 2 TB hard-drive used for storage. Until I disabled fast-boot the system was unable to shut-down/logout normally being stuck on an infinite loading screen.

Disabling Fast-boot has fixed the problem of infinite loading but has left a few problems in it's place. I am unable to resume torrent downloads as any download(which I save to the 2 TB drive) gives me cyclic redundancy check error. The application often randomly freeze and I have been unable to install steam as it is stuck forever applying updates. The desktop sometime randomly goes black and moves the application bar to the side.

I suspect the problem has to do with the disk as DISKPART is stuck with a blinking cursor indicating that the computer has trouble accessing a disk but given that the inbuilt system scan indicates that all the disks are problem-free I'm confused about the source of the problem.

Does anybody have any insight into how I can remedy this problem?

Comment: What "inbuilt system scan" are you talking about? Can you show a screenshot of it showing that the disks are okay? It does sound a lot like a failed disk or disks.

Comment: It's built-in error checking scan, that showed all the disks as lacking problems.

Comment: That doesn't really help. Without knowing what scan you are running it is hard to know what it is actually reporting or testing. There is more than one way to scan a disk that is "built in" so please be clear about what you are actually doing. If you are using `chkdsk` or something then it is entirely possible that all it is doing is checking that the filesystem structure is okay and not actually scanning for physical disk defects which is what it sounds like you have.

Comment: THhis is the scan I used:

Comment: https://s.aolcdn.com/os/help/vsta_cmptr_rc_prprts_tools_chck_now.gif

Comment: That scan will not tell you if there are physical defects with the disk, it is not a "deep" scan and (by default) does not do a scan of the physical disk surface or even tell you if the drive itself is defective. Using one of the SMART status tools (https://superuser.com/questions/29240/how-can-i-read-my-hard-drive-s-smart-status-in-windows-7) might give more information on the health of the drive.

Comment: "Check the volume for errors" only checks the file system metadata for inconsistencies. It is the same as a simple chkdsk . It does not read every block on the drive or even every block that's in use. chkdsk /r tries to read every block on the disk. This would show you the bad blocks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cyclic redundancy check error is something reported by a drive when the data on the disk is corrupt. The problem is likely in the drive itself but it could possibly be in the SATA controller or the system's power supply. I would replace the hard drive and see if the problems go away. The other problems might be fallout from this one, or might be independent.

Comment: Thanks, it was a hard-drive problem. removing the 2tb drive fixed the problem